# is there a way to use more than one action on a li element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If I click on the `i` tag inside the `li` tag it only triggers the `goTo()` function and not the `byebye()` function.

Is there a easy way to decide, if either the `li` or the `a` tag got clicked?

```
<ul>
  <li @click="goTo(list)">
    Check me up! <i @click="byebye(list)" class="fas fa-ban"></i>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: You can use `@click.stop` to prevent the event form bubbling up to the `<li>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment: you can use the [event modifier, `.stop`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers), to prevent the click event from bubbling up to the `<li>` parent: see proof-of-concept:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    goTo: function() {
      console.log('goTo');
    },
    byebye: function() {
      console.log('byebye');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li @click="goTo()">
      Check me up! <i @click.stop="byebye()" class="fas fa-ban">ICON</i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this would be to call a single function that then calls two other functions. So you call `goToAndByeBye(list)` which then calls `goTo()` and `byebye(list)`.

I believe you can also seperate two function calls like so:

```
<i @click="byebye(list); gotTo()">
```

If you want to figure out what element the event was called from, consider passing $event as a parameter in your HTML function call, which will contain information about the calling element.